# Schedule a disk snapshot on GKE

Tags: backup, authentication, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I'd like to schedule this command line to run every 12h on Google Container Engine:

```
gcloud compute --project "qvitoo-com" disks snapshot \
  "SPECIFIC_INSTANCE_ID" --zone "europe-west1-c" --snapshot-names \
  "DB-staging-$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ")"
```

We're running hosted Kubernetes.

This command line needs access to the gcloud API to succeed. How do I make this happen?

(I can't use [gcloud cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) because it's HTTP calls only, and [Kubernetes cron jobs are in alpha](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/), plus I don't know how to authenticate)

Answer (score 7):

Our solution is built on an open source tool called [k8s-snapshots](https://github.com/miracle2k/k8s-snapshots). This toll requires the use of PersistentVolumes but with annotations performs a snapshot at an interval. It also manages retention. [Our extension to it](https://github.com/hangar-technology/k8s-snapshots) notifies via slack if that's useful to you.  It runs as a separate service inside our k8s cluster and uses the authentication that's native on the GCE host the cluster is running on.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [snapshot-controller](https://github.com/linki/snapshot-controller). It's similar to k8s-snapshots, but has fewer fancy features. I couldn't get k8s-snapshots to work due to [this bug](https://github.com/miracle2k/k8s-snapshots/issues/2).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver  (beta on k8s 1.13)
It support snapshot and restore as k8s resource.

Comment: Adding the info from the link would improve your answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/backube/snapscheduler. It allows creating VolumeSnapshots for PVCs in GKE cluster